# using jquery to load content

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Ok here's the problem:
In my index page I have 4 tabs menu, Home/Contact/About/Faq and a #content div.
When I click on each of the tabs the result appears in the #content div.

The content of the Home button is already written in the Index page while all the other tabs are external pages. The following script can perfectly call external pages only.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/gf5US/

As you can see, on the first load, "Content of home tab" is shown, if you click on FAQ, faq.php is loaded, but then I can't go back to home.
How can I fix this so I could combine between showing external pages and local divs within the same index page? (one suggestion is to make the home an external page, but that's not what I want)

Comment: It'd be helpfull if you can add your html as well. Doesn't href include the .php already?

Comment: please post your full code using jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, only two ways are here to do this because one the content of `#content` is replaced by content of other tabs, you need to fetch the content of Home page back. Now its your choice to fetch it via Ajax or normal GET request.

One is to load the content of Home tab via Ajax in index page (by loading it with jQuery's load method in document ready event handler) and in that case your current script would work as it is. But, I don't know whey you don't want this.

Another approach can be load complete index page when user clicks on Home tab. For this script would be

```
$(function() {
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == 'home') {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    } else {
        $('#content').load(page + '.php');
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```